# Incorporating non-collinearity into RANSAC affine transform estimation

Tags: multicollinearity, model

The MATLAB code at [this](http://read.pudn.com/downloads106/sourcecode/graph/texture_mapping/436817/matlab/utvisToolbox/tutorials/SIFTtutorial/fit_robust_affine_transform.m__.htm) link can be used to estimate the affine transform between two sets of 2D points. The code makes the implicit assumption that neither of the point sets contain collinear points. However, I have data in which either the source or destination point sets (p0 and p1 in the code) *can* contain collinear points. Instead of trying to somehow remove collinearity in the sets, I wish to modify the RANSAC procedure so that collinear points become outliers.

In the initial model guess phase(code snippet from link below), 3 point pairs are selected at random. If I were to check here for collinearity of point pairs, would it **guarantee** that collinear points will be treated as outliers at the end of the procedure ?

```
for k = 1:num_guesses
  % Select 3 random constraints
  c = [ceil(rand * n)];
  for j = 2:3
     k = ceil(rand * n);
     while any(c == k)
        k = ceil(rand * n);
     end
     c = [c; k];
  end  
  ....(more code)
 end % loop on k
```

Some additional details: Analysis of my data reveals that even if the input points(p0) are not collinear, using the above code <strike>will</strike> can select inliers in such a way that output(p1) points can be collinear.

For example, in the toy data set at [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gztfB.jpg), no two points of the same color should be selected. Put another way, for each color, 2 points must become outliers.

Is it possible at all to enforce non-collinearity into this RANSAC based procedure?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is an approach like RANSAC needed? Why are ordinary least squares estimates or some standard robust version of them (such as IWLS) not adequate?

Comment: @whuber RANSAC is needed since not all pairings are valid. We want those which broadly agree according to our model to act as inliers and rest become outliers.

Comment: How does RANSAC compare to, say, IWLS (which is widely available and has a high breakdown point)?

Comment: I second whuber: in matlab you have an estimator of regression with the same breakdown that can handle exact fits [here](http://www.riani.it/MATLAB/FSDA_working_paper.pdf) and also [here](http://automatica.dei.unipd.it/public/Schenato/PSC/2010_2011/gruppo4-Building_termo_identification/IdentificazioneTermodinamica20072008/Biblio/Articoli/LIBRA%20a%20MATLAB%20Library%20for%20Robust%20Analysis.pdf)